# How to automatically update session_stared date after every request

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

I need to update session_started date after every request from client's side.
My zf2 session config

```
'cookie_lifetime'     => 60 * 60 * 24,
'remember_me_seconds' => 60 * 60 * 24,
'use_cookies'         => true,
```

and I set it in onBootStrap method in application module.php

```
$config        = $serviceManager->get('config');
$sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
$sessionConfig->setOptions($config['session']);
$sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
$sessionManager->start();
Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
```

so after login in cookies creation date sets as loggin date and expiration date 1 day after it. So I need update creation date to now after every request from client and
accordingly update expiration...

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer which satisfies me
[PHP Sessions Not Extending Cookie Expiration on Each Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791667/php-sessions-not-extending-cookie-expiration-on-each-request/15751774#15751774)

```
function my_session_start($maxtime = 300){
    // $maxtime = 300 for 5 minutes
    session_start();
    $_sess_name = session_name();
    $_sess_id = session_id();
    // Update cookie ;)
    setcookie($_sess_name, $_sess_id, time() + $maxtime, "/");
}
```

Comment: I ve tried this in ZF2, but session renews after every request. So I cant stay logged in