# Symfony 3 TokenAuthenticator end session

Tags: php, session, nginx, symfony

I am building a web application with Symfony3, Nginx, PHP7. 
For authorization i created a TokenAuthenticator class that extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator. I can authenticate with a token and logout manually.

If i don't logout manually the session seems to last forever.
I want the app to invalidate any sessions when the browser is closed.
All users should re-authenticate if it is a new browser session.

The session persists and i am not asked to re-authenticate even when i have restarted nginx, php fpm and cleared cache from cmd line.

My **TokenAuthenticator has this method**:

```
public function supportsRememberMe()
{
    return false;
}
```

**config.yml:**

```
session:       
    handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
    save_path: "/var/lib/php/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    cookie_lifetime: 0
```

**security.yml:**

```
main:
    guard:
        authenticators:
            - app.token_authenticator
    logout:
        path: logout
        target: /
        invalidate_session: true

    anonymous: false
```

**php.ini:**

```
session.cookie_httponly On  On
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
```

How do i remove/destroy the session/cookie(PHPSESSID) when the browser is closed?

there must be a simple trick to do this.

Edit:

Got a good explanation in this answer on why on the dev server the session mostly never expires https://stackoverflow.com/a/1505596/1249820

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by setting **session.gc_probability = 1** in php.ini, the default was 0.
                                                                                    The php cronjob **/etc/cron.d/php**  to clear sessions runs every 30 mins

```
09,39 * * * *  root [-x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean
```

**Verfiy that the cronjob has executed:**

```
`grep CRON /var/log/syslog | tail`
```