# PHP Session Data Randomly Gets Deleted

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

Please help this issue has been driving me crazy and I feel like I've researched everywhere and come up with no answers.

**Description of the Problem**
I am creating an intranet web application for my company using PHP, MySQL, Apache from WAMP.
I am having an issue where my $_SESSION data on the server is randomly getting deleted with no apparent reason (I'm sure there's a reason, I just can't catch it!!!).
What I have is an **index.js** file included in every HTML page displayed.  This JS file has the following code:

```
var refreshTime = 60000;    // 1 minute = 1000ms/1s * 60s/min = 60,000
//  Function called every refreshTime interval
window.setInterval( function() {    
    //  AJAX call to refreshSession.php simply calls session_start() in PHP
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: rootWebHostURL + "php/refreshSession.php",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Session refreshed via AJAX call in index.js");
            console.log("Dumping RAW JSON DATA");
            console.log(data);

            testobj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log("Dumping JSON PARSED DATA"); 
            console.log(testobj);

            if ( testobj.sessionIsEmpty )
            {
                alert('SESSION DATA IS EMPTY');
            }
        }
    });
}, refreshTime );
```

This portion makes an AJAX call to the server every 1 minute.  The PHP code called, calls **session_start()** to refresh the session and keep it's last access time within the limits of **gc_maxlifetime** (which I have set to 3600s or 1 hour) in the **php.ini** file.  I recently modified the code to make a browser alert whenever the session data is dropped.
The **refreshSession.php** code is shown below:

```
session_start();
$arrayForAJAX = session_get_cookie_params();
$arrayForAJAX['id'] = session_id();

$sessionLog = fopen('C:\\...\\Desktop\\AAPEC Project\\Log\\session_log_00.txt', 'a+');

$dateNow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$textToWrite = $dateNow . PHP_EOL . '===================' . PHP_EOL;

$sessionDataString = var_export( $_SESSION, true );

$textToWrite .= $sessionDataString . PHP_EOL . '==========================================' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

fwrite($sessionLog, $textToWrite);

$arrayForAJAX['sessionIsEmpty'] = false;
if ( empty($_SESSION) )
{
    $arrayForAJAX['sessionIsEmpty'] = true;
}

echo json_encode( $arrayForAJAX, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

What I've recently done in the refreshSession.php is write the contents of $_SESSION variable to a file, with a timestamp, every time refreshSession.php is called from AJAX.  See the contents of this 'log' file below.

```
2016-06-16 09:24:15
=================== array (   'workingStatus' => 'in_process',   'currentpage' => 'datacapture.tpl',   'visitedpages' =>    array (
    0 => 'stocknumber.tpl',
    1 => 'preflight.tpl',
    2 => 'general.tpl',
    3 => 'pxeactions.tpl',
    4 => 'timezone.tpl',
    5 => 'options.tpl',
    6 => 'datacapture.tpl',   ),   'stocknumber.tpl' =>    array (
    'stocknum' => '12345678',
    'tenDigitStockNumber' => '0012345678',   ),   'operationType' => 'new',   'preflight.tpl' =>    array (
    'hardware_class' => '0',
    'tot_sys_memory' => '1',
    'installed_os' => '0',
    'pxe_boot_method' => '0',   ),   'general.tpl' =>    array (
    'engineer' => 'Bill Hodges',
    'company_name' => 'af',
    'parent_pn' => 'afds',
    'network_location' => 'Images',
    'support_file_directory' => 'Images\\12345678',   ),   'pxeactions.tpl' =>    array (
    'pxe_boot_action' => '0',
    'pxe_boot_mode' => '0',   ),   'timezone.tpl' =>    array (
    'timezone' => '-7',   ),   'options.tpl' =>    array (
    'datacapture' => 'datacapture.tpl',
    'virusscan' => 'virusscan.tpl',   ),   'optionpages' =>    array (
    0 => 'datacapture.tpl',
    1 => 'virusscan.tpl',   ), )
==========================================

2016-06-16 09:25:15
=================== array (   'workingStatus' => 'in_process',   'currentpage' => 'datacapture.tpl',   'visitedpages' =>    array (
    0 => 'stocknumber.tpl',
    1 => 'preflight.tpl',
    2 => 'general.tpl',
    3 => 'pxeactions.tpl',
    4 => 'timezone.tpl',
    5 => 'options.tpl',
    6 => 'datacapture.tpl',   ),   'stocknumber.tpl' =>    array (
    'stocknum' => '12345678',
    'tenDigitStockNumber' => '0012345678',   ),   'operationType' => 'new',   'preflight.tpl' =>    array (
    'hardware_class' => '0',
    'tot_sys_memory' => '1',
    'installed_os' => '0',
    'pxe_boot_method' => '0',   ),   'general.tpl' =>    array (
    'engineer' => 'Bill Hodges',
    'company_name' => 'af',
    'parent_pn' => 'afds',
    'network_location' => 'Images',
    'support_file_directory' => 'Images\\12345678',   ),   'pxeactions.tpl' =>    array (
    'pxe_boot_action' => '0',
    'pxe_boot_mode' => '0',   ),   'timezone.tpl' =>    array (
    'timezone' => '-7',   ),   'options.tpl' =>    array (
    'datacapture' => 'datacapture.tpl',
    'virusscan' => 'virusscan.tpl',   ),   'optionpages' =>    array (
    0 => 'datacapture.tpl',
    1 => 'virusscan.tpl',   ), )
==========================================

2016-06-16 09:26:15
=================== array ( )
==========================================
```

I cut the contents of the file down here to save space.  There were about 10+ successfuly $_SESSION data writes before the first line, but as you can see the last write was an empty array. Indicating that there is no $_SESSION data.  I have attempted to use debug_backtrace() here to get information about where PHP was in the program and determine what scripts/functions were called that could be causing this problem. debug_backtrace(), however, returns an empty array when I tried using it in my refreshSession.php script.  From my research, it indicated that this is because refreshSession.php is the first and only script called.
**WHY?!?!?  Why would this code make 10+ or more successful session_start() calls and save $_SESSION data and then randomly drop data on one of the calls?**

I have the following settings in **php.ini** file that pertain to sessions/cookies:

```
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1
session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
```

which I realize, with the way I am doing things, will effectively keep this session alive forever since I'm refreshing the session every 1 min.  Which is fine for now, I just don't want data to drop out of nowhere in the middle of the app.

**Side Notes:**
I realize that cookie_lifetime = 0 will keep the cookie 'alive' on the browser until the browser is closed.  I realize the combination of session.gc_xxx variables will produce a probability of 1 for session garbage collection, which if I understand correctly will clear out old sessions that have not been 'modified' in the past 1 hour (since session.gc_lifetime = 3600s).  I have considered and even began writing code for user managed sessions using a DB to give me more control, but after more research, I do not think it is necessary for the simple task that I am trying to do here.

I am a complete novice at this stuff (recently graduated with a BSEE w/ Computer Information Systems minor, most of my knowledge about all this is from Google and StackOverflow) and have managed to create this web application, however I am by no means a web/php developer.  I probably have tons of errors in what/how I'm doing things in my code above.  Any constructive criticisms and links to improvement are appreciated as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236374/session-timeouts-in-php-best-practices  Be_Open's answer might help you out.  I think you might have to change your settings in you php.ini for your garbage collector.

Comment: @SariRahal thanks for your response.  I don't believe that Be_Open's answer is any help here.  I think I have a solid understanding of the PHP garbage collection process.  This is a low volume server probably a max of 10 users on at any one time.  With my current settings on my local dev PC, the probability of garbage collection is 1.  So every time I call session_start() which is every 1 minute, garbage collection runs and should delete session files that haven't been active in the past hour.  However, since I refresh my session every 1 minute, the session data should never be deleted

Comment: @SariRahal and in fact, it never does get deleted.  That session file always exists in my /tmp folder, however the data within it is what is getting deleted.  Not sure why though!!!!

Comment: Have you tried using a named session in order to verify you don't have something like unset session being called from a different app on the same server?

Comment: @devlincarnate No I have not.  Do you have a link to start me in the right direction?

Comment: You just set the name, `session_name("foobar");` , before calling `session_start();` .  The description on the [man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) states this.  If this fixes your problem, please let me know and I'll post it as an answer.  I'm just stabbing in the dark at one possibility so I don't know if it's actually an answer for your problem.